# Animate random numbers shuffle one by one in javascript

Tags: javascript

am trying to animate the random code that is for example 20345-6423-AGFDS and what am trying to do is when generating the code to animate it digit by digit.
The first digit shuffles and picks 2, then the second digit and picks 0 and on and on and on till the last.

```
<div id="code"></div>
<br>
<button onclick="generate()"> Generate Code </button>
```

JS

```
function generate() {
  document.getElementById("code").innerHTML = RanCode;
}
function randomString(length, chars) {
    var result = '';
    for (var i = length; i > 0; --i) result += chars[Math.round(Math.random() * (chars.length - 1))];
    return result;
}
function codeFunc(){
    return (
        randomString(5, '0123456789')
        + "-"
        + randomString(5, '0123456789')
        + "-"
        + randomString(5, 'ASDFGHJKL')
    );
}
var RanCode = codeFunc();
```

Example how i want them to shuffle one by one like the number inside the dice.
https://javascript-tutor.net/jSample/jsp_anidice.html

Answer (score 1):

https://jsfiddle.net/7s96d4by/

```js
const final = codeFunc(); // Initialize it with your function
const out = document.querySelector('output')

for (let i = 0; i < final.length; i++) {
  (function initPerCharAnimation(c) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      shuffle(c)
    }, 1000 * i)
  }(final.substring(0, i + 1).split('')))
}

function shuffle(final) {
  const original = final.concat()
  let i = 0
  for (; i < 9; i++) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      // TODO use random chars instead of numbers when final.at(-1) is a char
      final[final.length - 1] = Math.random() * 10 | 0
      out.innerText = final.join('')
    }, 100 * i)
  }

  setTimeout(() => {
    out.innerText = original.join('')
  }, 100 * i)
}
```

Comment: Maybe i was a little miss understood. Those numbers and letters wanted to be randomly generated not in a const. Also the letters to go from A to L for example and pick a random letter, same for numbers and only numbers from 1 to 9.

Comment: @Pass your `codeFunc()` is doing perfectly fine that. I updated my snippet to initialize it with your `codeFunc()` instead of a hardcoded value.

Comment: What if i want to use mixed numbers and letters? What i need to change in the code?
For example if it's number to shuffle numbers, if it's letter to shuffle random letters from A to Z for example.